# How do I get an attachment from a Lotus Notes email using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, lotus-notes

Is there something like `doc.GETITEMVALUE("Attachment")(0)`? Also, I can't find any documentation for the Domino API. Does anyone have a good resource for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access all file attachments on a NOtesDocument object using the document's EmbeddedObjects property. This will provide a handle to a collection of NotesEmbedded objects that you can iterate over. For each NotesEmbeddedObject, you should check the Type property, to see if its actually a file attachment (it could also be an embedded OLE object - see details [here](http://publib-b.boulder.ibm.com/lotus/c2359850.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/be982ccc25074a738525731b004a2b7c?OpenDocument)). To save an attachment to the file system, you can use the ExtractFile method of the EmbeddedObject.

The Notes "Designer Help" is found here: 
http://publib-b.boulder.ibm.com/lotus/c2359850.nsf/Main?OpenFrameSet
There is a section in there for "LotusScript/COM/OLE Classes" which should be helpful, and there is some sample code under each class.

**EDIT:** Actually, the EmbeddedObjects attribute of NotesDocument class will only include embedded OLE oebjcts. To get file attachments, you need to access the NotesRichTextItem object for the appropriate field - the EmbeddedObjects atribute of the NotesRichTextItem class does include file attachments. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798867/help-retrieving-attachments-from-a-lotus-notes-email-using-notes-api-and-vb-net) for sample code.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm still having a bit of a problem getting it to work though.  Can you take a look at my other question?  http://tinyurl.com/y9wofwb